# Beamer (Frankfurt theme) compilation discrepancy between latest and previous MiKTeX 2.9 releases

Tags: beamer, miktex2.9, miktex-update

I am compiling the same `beamer` presentation below using two versions of MiKTeX 2.9 that are installed on different Windows machines and I am getting different outputs.

The problematic output is the one associated with the latest release 2.9.6637-x64 (March 2018). The other machine has version 2.9.6361-x64 (August 2017) installed, and the compiled document is perfect.

Specifically, the preamble reads:

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\scriptsize\insertframenumber}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=5pt,text margin right=5pt}
```

Now suppose I want to have three sections in the presentation, with lots of frames in the first section and very few in the other two.

```
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
```

(...reproduce this frame many times within this section....)

```
\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Discrepancy:**
If I compile this with the earlier release (from August 2017), the output is as intended:

[image]

If I compile this with the latest release instead, I am getting navigation circles below the section headers in the navigation line, and the headers themselves are misaligned to reflect the different numbers of frames within each section (i.e. the headers for Section 2 and Section 3 are pushed further to the right).

[image]

I can hide the navigation circles in the latest release by adding

```
\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}
```

in the preamble. However, this does not take care of the header misalignment problem.

Any thoughts/solutions??

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\scriptsize\insertframenumber}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=5pt,text margin right=5pt}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@writeslidentry{\clearpage\beamer@notesactions}
\makeatother


\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}



\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Strange though that I should need to add code, right?

Comment: @mathfun123 Not strange. That it worked previously was just a side effect of a bug which was fixed